# Molecular Orbitals. Relative phase vs Bonding Anti-Bonding

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory

Most intro explanations of molecular orbital formation go something like this:
as two 1s orbitals of H atoms approach each other, their wave functions begin to overlap, and due to constructive and destructive interference, a bonding and an anti-bonding orbital is formed.

Since initially there can be an arbitrary difference in phase between the two 1s orbitals, does this mean that the energy of the molecular bond is a function of the phase difference and that a bonding orbital will form only for a range of phase differences ?

Comment: There is no range. The phases can be either similar or opposite.

Comment: And *either* a bonding MO forms (AOs are in phase) *or* an anti-bonding MO forms (AOs are of opposite phase). And what @IvanNeretin said.

Comment: OK.... but why?

Comment: Because all other combinations do not produce _eigenfunctions_.

Comment: When electrons get entangled in the bonding orbital, the wave function collapses, so must collapse into an eigenstate/function of the system, and only that combination is an eigenstate?  So the phase difference collapses....

Comment: @IvanNeretin what about partial interference ?
http://www.grandinetti.org/molecular-orbital-theory

Comment: @M.ghorab.  From that article:  In general, the energy difference between a bonding and anti-bonding orbital pair becomes larger as the overlap of the atomic orbitals increase.

Comment: However, I can see the argument that two 1s orbitals of opposite phase form an eigenbasis.  Each 1s orbital is in a linear superposition of that basis.  When they begin to interact a system with four eigenstates is formed, two corresponding to the bonding orbital and two to the antibonding one.  The system becomes a superposition of four states.  But measuring the energy results in a collapse, and the most likely eigenvalue is the energy that corresponds to opposite phases.

Comment: Correction:  But measuring the energy results in a collapse, and the most likely eigenvalue is the energy that corresponds to orbitals in-phases.